# TypeScript: flag class methods with extended Function prototype

Tags: typescript

I want to flag class methods by extending the Function prototype.

So I did this to extend the prototype:

```
interface Function {
    $flag(): Function
    __flagged__: boolean
}

Function.prototype.$flag = function (): Function {
    this.__flagged__ = true;

    return this;
};
```

Which works fine, but I'm unable to flag class methods like this.

```
class Foo {
    bar(): void: {
        // Do stuff
    }.$flag()
}
```

When trying to call the `.$flag()` method, the compiler throws an syntax error, which seems kind of strange, because it would create valid JavaScript.

Is there any way to "flag" a class method?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to "flag" a class method?

Inside the constructor

```
constructor(){
    this.bar.$flag();
}
```

> which seems kind of strange, because it would create valid JavaScript.

As soon as your in a Typescript class your "valid javascript" is not valid ecmascript 5 anymore.

Comment: This would result in every class creation calling the `$flag` function, which may be unexpected.

Comment: there is no such requirement written in the question.I'd say if one wants to affect a prototype write one at first place.  One dont have to write classes in Typescript one can still benefit from the typesystem,With classes ones loose most of the dynamic features of javascript . However ,what you want to do should be possible in ES6.

Comment: (It wasn't my question, I was just clarifying an aspect of your answer that may not have been clear.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda to achieve the same effect :

```
interface Function {
    $flag(): Function
    __flagged__: boolean
}

Function.prototype.$flag = function (): Function {
    this.__flagged__ = true;

    return this;
};

class Foo {
    bar = ((): void => {
        // Do stuff
    }).$flag()
}
```

You can do it for member variables that are functions as shown.

However what you are trying to do cannot be done *inline* because it is a syntax error. But you can do that in the constructor if you really want to as shown by mpm.

Comment: Except that the `bar` is no longer on the prototype, which may not be desirable.

Answer (score 0):

As you're essentially using ECMAScript 6 features to describe a class (with TypeScript extensions to add typing), the syntax you suggest is valid, is in fact not valid. You can't declare a function and then "flag" it in the way you're doing.

One alternative to the other suggestions made is to just call the function after the class has been defined:

```
class Foo {
    bar() { }
}

Foo.prototype.bar.$flag();
```

While it may lack in elegance, it's only done once for the class. It's admittedly not as nice as being to "attribute" the function.